# How to use the same @jsonproperty name int following example?

Tags: json, jackson

At any point of time i will be setting only one setter method but the JsonProperty name should be same for both . when i am compiling this i am getting an exception. How to set the same name for both .?

```
public String getType() {
    return type;
}

@JsonProperty("Json")
public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public List<TwoDArrayItem> getItems() {
    return items;
}

@JsonProperty("Json")
public void setItems(List<TwoDArrayItem> items) {
    this.items = items;
}
```

Comment: Why are you withholding the details of the compiler error?  It would be relevant, unless you like guessing games.

Comment: So how precisely do you expect Jackson to know which one to serialize at any given time?  After all, `null` is a perfectly serializable value.

Comment: I am getting this exception. 
 com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Conflicting getter definitions for property "Json":                                    Among the two setter methods one will be null at time .

Comment: Ah, well that's not a compile error is it? :-)

Comment: ok runtime error ... how to overcome this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jackson tends to favor common scenarios and good design choices for annotation support.

Your case represents a very uncommon scenario.  You have one field having two different meanings in different contexts.  Typically this would not be a favourable data format since it adds messy logic to the consumer on the other end...they need to divine what the "Json" property should mean in each case.  It would be cleaner for the consumer if you just used two different property names.  Then it would be sufficient to simply check for the presence of each property to know which alternative it's getting.

Your Java class also seems poorly designed.  Classes should not have this type of context or modes, where in one context a field is allowed, but in another context it's not.

Since this is primarily a smell with your design, and not serialization logic, the best approach would probably be to correct your Java class hierarchy:

```
class BaseClass {
}

class SubClassWithItems {
    public List<TwoDArrayItem> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    @JsonProperty("Json")
    public void setItems(List<TwoDArrayItem> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }
}

class SubClassWithType {
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    @JsonProperty("Json")
    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

That way your class does not have a different set of fields based on some runtime state.  If runtime state is driving what fields your class contains, you're not much better off than with just a `Map`.

If you can't change that, you're left with [custom serialization](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToCustomSerializers).